# Various Query Builder

Tags: oop, design-patterns, activerecord

I'm creating a framework MVC to build my applications. In my application I need to use several DBMS s and I need be prepared for that.

I'm thinking in to use Active Record pattern and it have the "connection" (abstract) associated. The Active Record don't know which DBMS to be used. So, I use Factory Method for have abstract which DBMS been used.

How will I build various queries (CRUD) ? Because each DBMS will need specific query.

I'm think that creating various classes "QueryBuilder" it will can to resolve (one class for each DBMS ).

What's think?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can use DAO Layer Pattern. This pattern hides the database specific details from the client. You can define the interface for CRUD operation which your DAO will implement.

In this way, even your DB changes in future, client of DAO layer don't have to worry about the changes.

Refer below wiki page for more details about this pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

Comment: I'm doing this. My question is about the query builder (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,LIMIT) that can be different.

If build a class "QueryBuilder" for each one. For example: MySQLQueryBuilder.

QueryBuilder will be passed to method execute of Connection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the intent is to insulate the various ActiveRecord objects from the SQL syntax variances between the DBs?

You didn't define what you exacty intended with a design for your query bulder, but I've done once with methods like `AddSelection(colName)`, `AddCriteria(colName, ComparisonEnum, value)`, etc.  If that is your approach then if your queries are small/simple enough then a query builder would work.  BUT as soon as you need the ability to build complex joins or inner subqueries then you may hit a wall with that approach.

If you need to handle arbitrarily difficult queries then another option is to create a converter or translator.  If you were to define a canonical query format, then each DBMS-specific convert would know how to convert from that canonical format to the DB-specific syntax.  You've really got to need this functionality to make it worth the effort though.

And finally, your other appraoch is to subclass the ActiveRecord for each DB.  So if you have an EmployeeRecord class you can subclass it with OracleEmployeeRecord, MySqlEmployeeRecord, MsSqlServerEmployeeRecord, and the like.  Then use an abstract factory to create the appropriate ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is if I to make as you said, I would not could do dynamic. Imagine make a class for each model and for each DBMS. This is crazy.

I want which be easy my job. I want to do any system without make all again. It's a framework. If any programmer come in enterprise, they will worry only with the business layer.

Comment: I assume you are referring to my third option. I don't have my copy of Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture here in the office, but with ActiveRecord you typically do define a class to encapulate the row structure for each table. You could then use inhertitence to put the DBMS-specific code. It is a valid option, but you will have to weigh the pros and cons for your own use-case.